# EditText data not being passed over without button click

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am building an app where you can upload images to my company server

My problem is that I have a login screen with Email, Password and Client ID(in LoginActivity)

Now The data you enter there is passed to another Activity(CameraActivity) and that is used to build a URL with Uri.Builder.
The data is being saved within the edittext boxes BUT it is only being passed(using intents) to the other activity on the button click so, you have to go back to the login screen and click the button to reSubmit the data for every upload and everytime you start the app(The Data is stored within the textboxes but it is not being passed to the other activity without the button click), for the URI.Builder to work and give the entered information to the URL.

I want the client to enter that information ONCE and click the Button ONCE and then it is stored and used everytime regardless of the app being exited etc.

**Login Activity, This activity has the edittext boxes and the entered information is being saved but not passed to the other activity without the button click**

```
  public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String ID = "id";
String EMAIL = "email";
String PASS = "pass";
private SharedPreferences mPreference;
EditText email, password, id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    email=findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
    password=findViewById(R.id.pwdtext);
    id=findViewById(R.id.clientid);
    Button loginBtn=findViewById(R.id.button);

    mPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    id.setText(mPreference.getString(ID, ""));
    email.setText(mPreference.getString(EMAIL, ""));
    password.setText(mPreference.getString(PASS, ""));

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           EMAIL =email.getText().toString();
         PASS =password.getText().toString();
          ID =id.getText().toString();

            mPreference.edit().putString(ID,ID).apply();
            mPreference.edit().putString(EMAIL, EMAIL).apply();
            mPreference.edit().putString(PASS, PASS).apply();

            Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                    CameraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("clientId", ID);
            intent.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
            intent.putExtra("password", PASS);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Use sharedpreference to store data. And use startActivityForResult() and implement onActivityResult() and handle everything so that after coming back in login screen user dont need to click resubmit button.

Comment: So must i just replace mprefrence with sharedprefrence or what?? I have only been doing coding for about 2 weeks, so any help would be apreciated

Comment: Yes go ahead. Use sharedpreference in CameraActivity to retrieve saved data.

Comment: sorry i really can;t figure out how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the question comment, SharedPreferences is a good option.

```
SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
}

void setEmail(Context context, String email) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(context).edit();
    editor.putString("EMAIL", email);
    editor.apply();
}

String getEmail(Context context) {
    return getPreferences(context).getString("EMAIL", "");
}
```

Above is an example of how you can put things and retrieve things from the shared preferences. Since you have more than an email to store (user ID, etc...) you could even store an object as a gson so you would have to call only one function. But of course this is your call.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the `CameraActivity` if data exist in `SharedPreferences`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    email=findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
    password=findViewById(R.id.pwdtext);
    id=findViewById(R.id.clientid);
    Button loginBtn=findViewById(R.id.button);

    mPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    //Check if data exist
    if(mPreference.contain(ID))
      {

        Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                    CameraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("clientId", mPreference.getString(ID, ""));
            intent.putExtra("email", mPreference.getString(EMAIL, ""));
            intent.putExtra("password", mPreference.getString(PASS, ""));
            startActivity(intent);
      }

    //Rest of the code
}
```

Cheers :)